# Unable to find view Razor .Net Core app

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using Razor outside MVC.  I would like to render view as string. Here is my method:

```
    public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model)
    {            
        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { RequestServices = _serviceProvider };
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = _viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewName, false);
            if (viewResult.View == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{viewName} does not match any available view");
            }

            var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
            {
                Model = model
            };

            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                actionContext,
                viewResult.View,
                viewDictionary,
                new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),
                sw,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );

            await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I've created Views folder and pasted there few views. All the files has Copy to Output Directory - Copy always. But I am getting next  here

```
  var viewResult = _viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewName, false);
```

viewResult has property Success which is always false and also has property SearchedLocations with values: "/Views/Shared/Email.cshtml" and "/Views//Email.cshtml". Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Default view locations are `/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml` and `/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml`

Probably the controller doesn't exist (and razor can't find controller), so it's `/Views//Email.cshtml` in your case.

You can add custom location by adding a new view location expander:

```
public class ViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        var locationWithoutController = "/Views/{0}.cshtml";
        return viewLocations.Union(new[] { locationWithoutController });
    }

    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Register you expander in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc()
        .AddRazorOptions(options =>
        {
            options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new ViewLocationExpander());
        });
    }
```